# Give root access to C/C++ native side of an Android application using JNI, it seems to be impossible

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, root

I'd like to make the native code gain root access, even if the Java side correctly has root privileges... and it seems to be quite challenging.

**Example app:**

*Java side*

```
[...]
Log.d(TAG, "JAVA ROOT? " + rootManager.runCommand("id -u").getMessage()); // has the process 
root access?
rootTest(); // this is the native C function
Log.d(TAG, "JAVA ROOT? " + rootManager.runCommand("id -u").getMessage()); // check again
[...]
```

*C side*

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_MainActivity_testRoot(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {

    FILE *fp;
    char path[1035];

    fp = popen("id -u", "r");
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path), fp) != NULL) {
        printf("C ROOT?: %s\r\n", path);
    }
    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

*Output*

```
JAVA ROOT? 0 // -> Yeah, root!
C ROOT?: 10114 // -> :(
JAVA ROOT? 0 // -> Java side still has root.
```

I don't know why, but when the process executes his native code, it loses root permissions.
Is this for a sort-of security reason?
If yes, can it be disabled?

Comment: Won't you have to use `rootManager` to be root in the C side?

Comment: @JL2210 Well, rootManager is just an object instance, nothing special. It could be replaced with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...");` or anything similar: it just executes a shell command. On the C side, `execl("su")` didn't help.

Comment: Maybe `su -c ...`? Unless `su` on Android is different from the Unix `su`; it has been a while since I've used the terminal on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `rootManager.runCommand` to magically elevate your process or thread to root. The best you can do is spawn a different process (that's what `runCommand` does) as root and talk to it using various IPC mechanisms.